# ClassNotFoundException for 'com.google.common.collect.Lists'

Tags: java, spring, guava, noclassdeffounderror

I built a jar for my project which is based on spring boot. As soon as I launch a certain function, I get the following exception:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists] with root cause
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Lists

I already added guava in my dependecies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and also tried other versions like 23.6-jre and 24.1-jre but nothing seems to work..

The occurence of the exception in my code is when using

```
return Lists.reverse(myList);
```

At this point I have no clue what could possibly be the issue and I am very grateful for any help!

Edit:

When I try it with 
   mvn install
I get the following error message:

> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
>   [ERROR] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin must be a valid version but is 'RELEASE'. @ line 85, column 26
>    @
>   [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR]   The project com.boot.backend:AyMaps:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\AyMaps\pom.xml) has 1 error
>   [ERROR]     'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin must be a valid version but is 'RELEASE'. @ line 85, column 26
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException

and here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.boot.backend</groupId>
<artifactId>AyMaps</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<description>Routenplaner für OSM-Daten</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Topobyte</id>
        <url>http://mvn.topobyte.de</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>24.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.topobyte</groupId>
        <artifactId>osm4j-pbf</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.topobyte</groupId>
        <artifactId>osm4j-utils</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.topobyte</groupId>
        <artifactId>osm4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.boot.backend.GeoController</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <addResources>true</addResources>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemble-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: did you try to move your local .m2 `mv ~/.m2/repository ~/.m2/repository.bak` and then building your jar again?

Comment: No have not. Where can I find this local .m2?

Comment: it is by default under your home directory. Windows `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.m2\repository`

Comment: it may also be `C:\Documents and Settings\{your-username}\.m2` you may also have an environment variable M2_HOME you can check for by running `echo %M2_HOME5` in a cmd prompt

Comment: After doing this, my project will not be able to get any packages:
Error:(5, 32) java: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
Error:(6, 46) java: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
Error:(7, 1) java: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist

Comment: are you using `mvn install` to create your jar?

Comment: No, I am simply using the built in IntelliJ function 'Build Artifacts'.

Comment: could you post your entire pom.xml and also try using `mvn install` from the location where your pom.xml is?

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: @A.Ka. forget that IntelliJ thingie. Always build on the command line using mvn clean install, or use the dedicated Maven runner tools in IntelliJ.

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd I am doing this right now (and also changed the maven version in pom.xml to valid one) but it gives me a BUILD FAILURE (updated the post)

Comment: Change maven-assembly-plugin version from RELEASE to 3.1.0

Comment: Got the same message trying to run Jira Plugin: https://glot.io/snippets/f7hrahzvts